# Sectioned ListView only showing one item

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have created a sectioned `list-view` but it is displaying only one item.

The issue is that the `List View` only shows the first item. The `getItemViewType()` always returns the first condition in it. It replies `List is of generic Object type`, so I have to check the type of item at every position.

```
        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            Log.d("replies","replies list size : "+replies.size());
            return replies.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return replies.get(i);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            if (replies.get(position) instanceof ReplyDataAdapter)
            {
                Log.d("replies","instance of reply data adapter");
                return REPLY;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("replies","instance of reply on reply data adapter");
                return REPLYONREPLY;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }
```

Comment: That will happen if all the items in replies are instance of ReplyDataAdapter.

Comment: Check that the list view's height is not `wrap_content`, and that the list item view's height is not `match_parent`. If the list height is `wrap_content` it may be incorrectly sizing itself too small. If the list item's height is `match_parent`, each item will take up the entire height of the list view resulting in the appearance of only showing one item.